# Nested templates issue

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a nested template class declared like this:

```
template<typename T>
class IDMap
{
private:
    struct Item {
        uint16_t mVersion;
        T mItem;

        template <typename... Arguments>
        Item(uint16_t version, Arguments&&... args);
    };

    // ....
}
```

Later on I want to define the constructor of `item`, here is my attempt:

```
template <typename T, typename... Arguments>
IDMap<T>::Item::Item(uint16_t version, Arguments&&... args) : mVersion(version), mItem(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...)
{
}
```

The above dosn't compile though, it simply says `'IDMap<T>::Item::{ctor}' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration`. Something is missing - what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename... Arguments>
IDMap<T>::Item::Item(uint16_t version, Arguments&&... args) : mVersion(version), mItem(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...)
{
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4b542f9daffe35f)